# pyTorch: Creating a dataset

Tags: pytorch

I got a big pandas dataframe with time based measurement data (sensor values, the time information does not need to be an input to the network). 
This dataframe is put into a tensor and then loaded with torch.Dataloader.

The dataloader is extremly slow, the GPU utilization is ~3%.

As you can see in the code below the dataset is put into a tensor an then put into a torch.utils.data.DataLoader. This loader is then used with enumerate(Dataloader).

During my research I found the torch.utils.data.TensorDataset, but when I try to put the tensor into this type I get the error:
TypeError: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got list

Any suggestions about that?

As well I found the samplers from torch. But when to use these, as I am getting out data of the dataloader, just very slow.

```
    dataset = big_dataframe_flt.values
    (looks like: array([[ 0.17114914, -0.67040386, -0.72875149, ..., -0.51023438,
     0.49735906, -0.74075046],
   [ 0.17114914, -0.67088608, -0.72631001, ..., -0.53046875,
     0.49741296, -0.74127526],)

    dataset = torch.tensor(dataset).float()
    dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(dataset)

    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        for batch_idx, data in enumerate(data_loader):
            data = Variable(data).to(device)
            recon_batch, mu, var = model(data)

            # Backprop and optimize
            loss = loss_function(recon_batch, data, mu, var)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()


data = Variable(data).to(device)
```

```
TypeError: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got list
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because `TensorDataset` returns a *tuple* of tensors as an output. If you `print(dataset[0])` you will see `(tensor([ 0.1711, -0.6704, -0.7288, -0.5102,  0.4974, -0.7408]),)` rather than `tensor([ 0.1711, -0.6704, -0.7288, -0.5102,  0.4974, -0.7408])`. So you have to either write `data = Variable(data[0]).to(device)` or destructure the tuple in your loop `for batch_idx, (data, ) in enumerate(data_loader):`. This should allow you to work with `DataLoader`.

That being said, if your data is low-dimensional, the `DataLoader` code is not very efficient because you have to perform a lot of sampling operations, paying the Python interpreter overhead with each one - in other words, this code will not benefit much from vectorization. You can partially remedy this by increasing the number of workers, but in the end the most performant version would probably be to write your own sampler which indexes the data tensor with an integer array of length 100, instead of sampling it with an integer 100 times and then concatenating the results. Depending on how expensive your GPU code is and the dimensionality of the data, you may or may not be able to saturate your GPU with the simple `DataLoader` solution.

Comment: So if I unterstand you correctly the pytorch Dataloader is doing the slow method with indexing and then concatenating? Then I'll try to write my own loader, shouldn't be too tricky.

Comment: Will I benefit from using the TensorDataset type speedwise?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `TensorDataset` is doing the slow thing, but then `DataLoader` is parallelizing this slow thing - so you will definitely see improvements over what you are doing now. My point is that if you want the fastest possible code, you should probably roll your own way of loading data, which would use advanced indexing to slice the data tensor. But then you would need to your own `multiprocessing` solution, because this just won't fit the `DataLoader` API. So, in short - use `TensorDataset` + `DataLoader` with multiple workers and roll your own stuff if that is still too slow.

Comment: Thank you for your help!